# JQuery check if existing appending element in element if not append to class but not this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can I prevent reappending element if element in element already exists with this code?

```
<div class='weekHourValue' data-nameDay='Tuesday' data-week='34' data-day='10' data-month='5' data-year='2015'><div class='singleYearEvent'></div></div>
<div class='weekHourValue' data-nameDay='Tuesday' data-week='34' data-day='10' data-month='5' data-year='2016'></div>
```

and now I want to somethink like this

`$(".weekHourValue[data-month='5'][data-day='10'] {where not exist in element}").append("<div class='singleYearEvent'></div>");`

Is there any jquery function like this? thank you!

Comment: It seems like you should be able to use a jQuery selector to get all `weekHourValue` elements with the correct day and month, then check through each of them to see if any one of them has the appropriate child element via a filter function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
$(".weekHourValue[data-month='5'][data-day='10']").each(function(){
    if (!$(this).find(".singleYearEvent").length)
        $(this).append("<div class='singleYearEvent'></div>");
});
```

Comment: Not really, because there is no need to iterate/manipulate the filtered collection afterwards.

Comment: Ok thank, you I thinked that JQuery have somethink like `where this not in parrent`